# Bootstrap4 col-xs does nothing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've noticed that in BS4  alpha, col-xs-x does not do a darn thing. Even on their official site

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

If you were to go in and change a class from col to col-xs-5 for example, no class is applied. Change it to col-sm-5, works as intended. Whats the deal?

Comment: **col-xs-** was removed from the alpha-6 release so yeah it does nothing because it doesn't exist. See [shiplist](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20939) and the link you posted does not refer to any class of **col-xs-**, there is **col-xl-** though.

Comment: seems navbar-right is also gone. ughhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: It's simply been replaced not removed.